# Show that for every linear map $T:V\rightarrow V$ there exists $a\in F$ so that $Tv=av$ for all $v\in V$ if $V$ is $1$-dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Attempting my first problem on linear maps, and I'm fairly certain it's incorrect, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Here's the problem:

> Suppose that $V$ is 1-dimensional. Show that for every linear map $T:V\rightarrow V$ there exists $a\in F$ so that $Tv=av$ for all $v\in V$.

Suppose that $V$ is $1$-dimensional and choose an arbitrary $v \in V$. We know that $T(v)$ must output an element in $V$ and that output can be represented as $av$ for an appropriate $a \in F$ because any vector can be represented as a scalar multiple of $v$. Since we chose an arbitrary $v$, we can just apply this thinking for all vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take some non-zero vector $v_0$. This vector forms a (trivial) basis for $V$ as $V$ is $1$-dimensional by assumption. Hence *every* vector $v\in V$ is of the form $v=cv_0$ for some $c\in F$ as this are the linear combinations in a $1$-dimensional vector space.

Now, $T(v_0)\in V$ and hence $T(v_0)=av_0$ for some $a\in F$. Now take $v\in V$ arbitrary. As noted earlier $v=cv_0$ for some $c\in V$. But then

$$T(v)=T(cv_0)=c\, T(v_0)=b(av_0)=a(bv_0)=av$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm slightly confused because aren't we supposed to prove that $T(v) = av$? In other words, why do we need to include vector $w$? Does it not suffice to just say $T(v) = av$ because every vector can be constructed by multiplying vector $v$ with a scalar?

Comment: @beginner $v$ is fixed. You *know* that $T(v)=av$ for some $a\in V$ as $v$ (if chosen non-zero) is a basis for $V$ and hence every possible output $T(v)=v'$ can be seen as a multiple of $v$ (as this are the $1$-dimensional linear combinations). After we have chosen $v$ arbitrarily we just show that every other vector $w$ obeys the same transformation law.

Comment: @beginner I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Okay, I think I get the solution. My source of confusion was: "Why can't we just pick an arbitrary $v$. We know $T(v)$ must output an element in $V$ and that output can be represented as $av$ because any vector can be represented as a scalar multiple of $v$. Since we chose an arbitrary $v$, we can just apply this thinking for all vectors." Is it necessary to explicitly bring in another vector $w$?

Comment: Yes I understand. Thank you!

Comment: @beginner I see. I think it's misleading of me to not stick to your original notation.

Comment: Ohhhh, I think I understand my confusion. You're fixing a vector and having it act as a basis, and then constructing every vector out of that fixed, basis vector. But I was more along the lines of "Choose an arbitrary vector and let this vector be a basis, call it $v$. Because $v$ is a basis, $T(v) = av$. And then I kept repeating this process for ALL vectors, so each vector acted as its OWN basis. Put simply, I was essentially constructing a new basis for every vector. I much prefer your proof but I'm wondering whether that argument works.

Comment: @beginner Exactly. I thought that this might be the reason behind your confusion. Fixing the basis vector ensures that we get the same $a$ and not a different for every single vector.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @beginner Glad to help!